# ArrayList value is being overrided?

Tags: java

I am reading values from the database by using a list of array string in each time I read a new row it keeps override the old row, why this happing?
Here is my code.

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
String[] row = new String[columnCount];
while(resultSet.next()) {
    for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        row[i] = resultSet.getString(i + 1);
    }
    table.add(row);
}
```

the expected result to be returned is

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| row 1 col 1 | row 1 col 2 | row 1 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| row 2 col 1 | row 2 col 2 | row 2 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

while I am getting this result

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| row 2 col 1 | row 2 col 2 | row 2 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| row 2 col 1 | row 2 col 2 | row 2 col 3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

but if I am using this code block the issue is being resolved and the data is being returned as expected.

```
List<String[]> table = new ArrayList<>();
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
int columnCount = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while(resultSet.next()) {
    String[] row = new String[columnCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        row[i] = resultSet.getString(i + 1);
    }
    table.add(row);
}
```

Comment: put this `String[] row = new String[columnCount];` inside the first while loop.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the first piece of code should produce the required results?

Comment: What do you think `String[] row = new String[columnCount]; ... table.add(row);` does?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I think the first piece should produce the expected results but why it's not, that's why I'm asking? I am adding the results to the row then is being added to table so what it going there if initialized inside or outside the while ?

Comment: @Pshemo its add a new row to the arraylist

Comment: The problem with the first piece of code is that you are reusing the row variable. Each iteration of the while loop, you use the same object to set values and add the same object to the list.

Comment: `String[] row = new String[columnCount];` creates array for String elements, `table.add(row);` adds *that* array (it can be added multiple times which you are doing in first example). If you use same array in loop like `row[i]=...` then you are replacing previous data in that array's cell with new data, but since list contains references to same array you are seeing data from that array in each iteration.

Comment: Thanks all to conclude Java is pass-by-value. When we pass the value of an object, we are passing the reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example code snippet, you're constructing a single array of String's consecutively adding the *same reference* to the accumulator list in every iteration of the while loop.

So, you're adding *the same string array reference* to the accumulator list `columnCount` number of times and they all refer to the same object in memory. This is why you're receiving unexpected results.

On the other hand, the second example code snippet *constructs a new distinct string array on each iteration of the while loop*, hence receiving the expected results.